# Insert CSS line in React code

Tags: css, reactjs

this is my code :

```
{
        delay > 0
        ? <strong className="history__late"> {delayDayConst}j {delayHourConst}h {delayMin}m <FormattedMessage {...globalMessages.inProgressAndLate} />
         </strong>
        : delay < 0 
        ? <span className="history__advance"> - {delayDayConst}j {delayHourConst}h {delayMin}m <FormattedMessage {...globalMessages.inProgressAndAhead} /></span>
        : <span className="history__break"><FormattedMessage {...globalMessages.break} /></span> 
 }
```

I only want to insert a CSS line on my condition, this CSS line point to another element not present in the function. I try some of things but no found a solution.

PS: sorry for my bad englsih.

Comment: The problem is not clear

Comment: @Harikrishnan When delay > 0, I want to change the color of another element in my page, so point the CSS of that element.

Comment: can you provide the code for that element too

Comment: @Harikrishnan It's just a <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use state for css class.Refer the following example.Here i consider the delay is passed as props

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor({ props }) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        class:'class1'
    };
  }
 componentWillMount() {
       if(this.props.delay >0 )
         { 
            this.setState({class:class1})
         }
       else {
                this.setState({class:class2})
            }
   }
  render() {
    return  <div><p className={this.state.class}>hello</p></div>; // replace with your condition
  }
}
```